# python etree cannot find elements

Tags: python, elementtree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<adsf version="1.1" xmlns="asdf2123.asd">
  <someData type="def" scope="all">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2002-08-12:00:12" action="created" user="root" >start</log>
    </header>

    <node class="aclass" operation="create" distName="root/aclass-1" version="F7">
      <p name="locationName">middle</p>
      <p name="release">09_1040</p>
      <p name="title">asdf</p>
      <p name="label">asdr</p>
    </node>

    <node class="UNIT" operation="create" distName="root/aclass-1/unit" version="F7">
      <p name="isTrue">true</p>
      <p name="type">A</p>
      <p name="typeExpected">B</p>
    </node>
  </someData>
</adsf>
```

Now i have this part of code. For now, i want to gel list of 'node' objects.
It prints nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
class MyClass(object):
    def myMethod(self,file):
        return ET.parse(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
tree = MyClass.myMethod(os.path.join('<PATH>', 'asd.xml'))
for node in tree.findall('.//node'):
    print(node.tag)
```

As this question looks duplicate, I'd like to add solution:
Seems that xmlns is true problem of this parser. Best way is just to asume this parser as bugged and unusable and swith to dom or minidom parser, that seems just better solution.

Comment: It appears that the use of `xmlns="asdf2123.asd"` is causing the problem, at least in my tests. If you remove this, it works but you should try with a valid parameter.

Comment: I have only read access to file.

Comment: Read access is okay. Also read the answer in the duplicate question. It might help.

Comment: Ha. Changed parser to minidoc. Works as charm! I am never going to switch back :)